# ProgressDialog dismisses after rotating the screen

Tags: android, android-activity, dialog, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I use a Service to upload files.  While a file is being uploaded, I display a ProgressDialog.

When I rotate the screen the ProgressDialog dismisses.

How can I keep the ProgressDialog around?

I'd rather not override onConfigurationChanged.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android should [handle this automatically](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/51d07454549326c9#) if you show your dialog with the `showDialog(int)` method.

Comment: Awesome, thanks!  When my activity gets destroyed do I need to call showDialog from onCreate or will the activity automatically show the dialog again until I call dismiss?

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on Dalmas' suggestion, if you happened to be like me, where you created the dialog in a separate class for managing the async task, then one line might be all you need to add:

```
mProgressDialog.setOwnerActivity((Activity)mContext);
```

This allows the Activity to manage the dialog.  A longer snippet for reference...

```
public DownloadCatalog(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
}

public void startDownload() {
    mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
    mProgressDialog.setOwnerActivity((Activity)mContext);
    mProgressDialog.setMessage("Downloading \n" + remoteDirectory);
    mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
    mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);


    new DownloadFileAsync().execute(fileUrl);
}


class DownloadFileAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        mProgressDialog.show(); 
    }
```